# amps were lower on ohms law math than what I read with live at the equipment?

Tags: ohms-law

When using ohms law on a residential A/C unit I got 7.3, But when using the multimeter it dropped to 5.5. What can cause this?

Comment: The A/C is not a resistor. A motor has very different impedances at DC, AC (startup) and AC (running).

Comment: A DMM cannot measure real vs reactive power. But a True RMS power meter can measure real part of load impedance.

Comment: 7.3 what, carrots?

Answer (score 1):

Several possible reasons:

1) The resistance is different when more current flows. The ohmmeter will put a small current, measure the voltage, and calculate the resistance. The actual circuit may be using a much larger current that changes the resistance (heating element)

2) The impedance is inductive (motor) or capacitive.

3) There is a residual voltage from a capacitor. The ohmmeter requires a completely powered off circuit.